# Reason for not using static variables?

Tags: c++, c

I thought using static variables might cause ambiguity in readability of the code but nothing special. But now, I know that there are 5 data sagments: text, data, bss, heap, stack. text segment is for code, data seg. is for declared variables, bss seg. is for undeclared variables, heap is for pointers, and stack if for variables of functions.

Would it be better not to use static variable over local variable to minimize the size the program takes on computer when running?

I'm pretty sure static variable and global variable are saved in bss or data segment. And the size of bss and data segment does not change after compiled. And for heap and stack, they get released once used, so there is nothing to worry about size.

Am I right in thinking this?

Comment: static variables normally make your code non-reentrant, so you should try to avoid them as much as possible.

Comment: You should use storage types (like every language feature) according to what you need (regardless of where it might be stored). If you need something to be static, make it `static`. If you need something to be automatic, make it "function local", i.e. automatic. Besides, automatic storage is almost certain to be not only safer (in terms of reentrancy) but also faster.

Comment: I believe that these concerns are only relevant in very small memory environments, e.g. embedded microcontrollers, where the size of the executable could be important. For all other machines, most notably any PC past 1985, the criteria is simply what's the appropriate storage class for your use. Also note that while objects with static storage durations are zero-initialized, that initialization is not only dirt cheap but also happens exactly once per program run.

Comment: @SergeyL. Is it always good to make my code reentrant? What would be good practice to write codes reentrant besides not usning staic variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Text segment is for code, data seg. is for declared variables, bss seg. is for undeclared variables

So far you are right.

> heap is for pointers

No. Heap is for data allocated via `malloc()` and, in the case of C++, `new`.

The pointers are stored wherever you put them (data, bss, stack).

> and stack for variables of functions.

And for function arguments.

> Would it be better not to use static variable over local variable to minimize the size the program takes on computer when running?

The size is quite the same while the variable exists (in data/bss vs. on stack); if it doesn't exist, the stack-based approach wins.

The stack-based approach wins as well concerning other aspects: reentrancy (as already was said) and readability.

> And for heap and stack, they get released once used, so there is nothing to worry about size.

Of course you have to worry about the size here as well. Just go and try to allocate one million chunks of 16 MiB in size (at least on a 32 bit machine), and you'll see...

You should use `static` variables when you need them, and others if you don't.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable `static` it means it will have to be initialised with `0`.So it

is the extra effort for the compiler to initialise it with `0` . So if you have say

`100` variables then the work of the compiler will be `100` times than of declaring them

`automatic`.But `automatic` variables are not initialised with any value so they contain

`garbage`.So it is advisable not to use `static` as long as needed.

Comment: That's not at all the real point. Initialization to 0 can be done by the OS, especially by the memory management routines which you can instruct to deliver a page filled with 0. On other platforms, the init routines have to do it themselves. But filling memory with 0 is one of the cheapest operations, so that's not to worry about.